# NSCollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind not being called

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

In my `NSCollectionViewItem` I set up the code below.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: NSCollectionView.SupplementaryElementKind, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSView {
    let view = collectionView.makeSupplementaryView(ofKind: .sectionHeader, withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "sectionHeader"), for: indexPath)
    view.wantsLayer = true
    view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
    return view       
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: NSCollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> NSSize {
    return NSSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: 60)
}
```

However, when I place a `print()` in the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` function it never is executed. Also, no red header appears.

This is how I set up the `NSCollectionView`

```
public let collectionView: NSCollectionView = {
    let v = NSCollectionView(frame: NSRect.zero)
    v.wantsLayer = true
    v.layer!.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
    v.isSelectable = true
    v.backgroundColors = [NSColor.clear]
    v.allowsEmptySelection = false
    v.collectionViewLayout = {
        let l = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
        l.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        l.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        l.scrollDirection = NSCollectionView.ScrollDirection.vertical
        l.sectionInset = NSEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        return l
    }()

    return v
}()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The supplemental views (header and footer) are not collection view items. You need to implement those two methods on the `NSCollectionViewDelgateFlowLayout` object, not on your `NSCollectionViewItem` class.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

You can also set a default for the entire collection view:

```
l.headerReferenceSize = NSSize(width: 0, height: 50)
l.footerReferenceSize = NSSize(width: 0, height: 50)
```

When using `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout`, the default size of the header and footer is `NSSize.zero`, so the method to make the supplemental view is not called unless one of these techniques is used.